# struct dirent **foo to a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I'm trying to initialize a structure inside a function with scandir. I want to store all the files in a directory into an array and do some taks with them.

```
void main() {
    struct dirent **list;
    int n = read("/home/user", list);
    print(list, n);
    free(list);
}

int read(char *path, struct dirent **foo) {
    int n = scandir(path, &foo, 0, alphasort);
    return 0; 
}

void print(struct dirent **foo, int n) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        struct dirent *entry;
        entry = nameList[i];
        printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
        free(entry);
    }
}
```

Why `read(char*, struct dirent**)` causes a `segmentation fault`?
It gives no error when I buid it and I am a bit lost here.

Comment: where is 'path' and 'foo' defined?

Comment: @tinky_winky yes sorry, I'm passing a string directly. I'll edid it right now.

Comment: Please do not edit the code after answers have been posted, it makes the whole discussion inconsistent.  I reverted you last edit, which was incorrect anyway.

Comment: @chqrlie ok, sorry. I just edited because it was a mistake I did while writen the question. It suposse to return n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int scandir(const char *dirp, struct dirent ***namelist,
              int (*filter)(const struct dirent *),
              int (*compar)(const struct dirent **, const struct dirent **));
```

scandir takes pointer to pointer to pointer, but in function

```
int read(char *path, struct dirent **foo) {
    int n = scandir(path, &foo, 0, alphasort);
    return 0; 
}
```

you are passing address of local pointer to pointer. Pass address of pointer instead:

```
int read(char *path, struct dirent ***foo) {
    int n = scandir(path, foo, 0, alphasort);
    return 0; 
}

void main() {
    struct dirent **list;
    int n = read("/home/user", &list);
    print(list, n);
    free(list);
}
```

Moreover:

The scandir() function returns the number of directory entries selected.  On error, -1 is returned, with errno set to indicate the cause of the error.

So you should change your read function if you want anything to be printed and handle error in main:

```
int my_read(char *path, struct dirent ***foo) 
{
    return scandir(path, foo, 0, alphasort); 
}
```

In main():

```
    int n = read("/home/user", &list);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        perror("scandir failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Can you point me some good reads about pointers and functions? I alwais get stuck with them.

Comment: @blackout please read C book written by Brian W. Kernighan & Dennis M. Ritchie

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

- `read` is the name of a POSIX function defined and used by the C library, use a different name for your function.
- you modify the argument `foo` in your read function, not the local variable `list` passed by value in `main`. You must pass the address of `list` and change the prototype to `int read_entries(const char *path, struct dirent ***foo)`.
- you should return the number of entries from your read function.
- you `free` the entries in function `print`: this is misleading, you should use a specific function to free the structures and the array allocated by `scandir`.
- the prototype `void main()` is incorrect.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int read_entries(const char *path, struct dirent ***foo) {
    return scandir(path, foo, NULL, alphasort);
}

void print_entries(struct dirent **list, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", list[i]->d_name);
    }
}

void free_entries(struct dirent **list, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(list[i]);
    }
    free(list)
}

int main() {
    struct dirent **list;
    int n = read_entries("/home/user", &list);
    if (n < 0) {
        printf("cannot enumerate directory /home/user: %s\n",
               strerror(errno));
    } else {
        print_entries(list, n);
        free_entries(list, n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i am already using different name. I just translate literally the word read from my native lenguage.

Comment: @blackout: It is a good idea to use english names for functions and variables in your own code, it makes it easier to share with other programmers around the world.